# Import CSV with import-excel plugin in grails

Tags: csv, grails, plugins, import

I'm using import-excel plugin to import data in .xls format. The plugin states that it can import .csv, but I can't find any examples of this. I don't want to use a different plugin, or write code around the underlying library. Can anyone point me to some documentation or an example?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this and am posting it if it might help someone else, it works for me you obviously have to taylor it to your document etc.

https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import/blob/master/test/projects/sample/src/groovy/sample/BookExcelImporter.groovy

specifically you are interested in this part below

```
static class BookCsvImporter extends AbstractCsvImporter {

    static Map configMap = [
        startRow: 1,
        columnMap: [
            0: 'title',
            1: 'author',
            2: 'numSold'
        ]
    ]

    List<Map> getBooks() {
        getData(configMap)
    }

    def copyToExcel(BookExcelImporter excelExporter) {
        def booksMapList = this.getBooks()
        excelExporter.setBooks(booksMapList)
        return excelExporter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative when you don't want to create a new class. Also you can specify the source of the data directly:
 
readFromStream(inputStream)
readFromFile(String fileName)
readFromUrl(URL url)

```
static Map configMap = [
    startRow: 1,
    columnMap: [
        0: 'title',
        1: 'author',
        2: 'numSold'
    ]
]

AbstractCsvImporter csvbook = new AbstractCsvImporter(){
    }.readFromStream(file.inputStream)

def mapList = csvbook.getData(configMap)
```