# grails excel-import plugin csv issue

Tags: csv, grails

I am using grails Excel-import plugin to import Excel and csv files.For excel files it works fine.But I am having a tough time to make it work for csv. I refferd the code in the following stack overflow Question
[Import CSV with import-excel plugin in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830546/import-csv-with-import-excel-plugin-in-grails)
I tried to bind the csv file with my csvImport class by using readFromFile and readFromURL method(these i found in the plugin'test directory in bootstrap.groovy).this is the code for my csvImport file

```
    import org.grails.plugins.excelimport.*

   class csvImport extends AbstractCsvImporter {
   static Map configMap = [
    startRow: 1,
    columnMap: [
        0: 'title',
        1: 'author',
        2: 'numSold'
     ]
   ]

  def readCsv(File fileName){
    read(fileName)
 }
 List<Map> getList(CONFIG_COLUMN_MAP) {
    getData(CONFIG_COLUMN_MAP)
}
List<Map> createListFromCSV(CONFIG_COLUMN_MAP) {

    def csvList = this.getList(CONFIG_COLUMN_MAP)
    log.info("<<<csvList>>>>"+csvList)
}
```

and in controller i am trying to call it like this

```
        def csvImportIntance=new csvImport()
        csvImportIntance.readCsv(new File("D:\\Folder\\testCSV.csv"))
        def bookParamsList= csvImportIntance.createListFromCSV(CONFIG_COLUMN_MAP)
```

the file is ms-excel csv file.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you class name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: I changed class name to capital letter.